# State is not gatting update when using setstate in react with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am facing an issue regarding the *setstate*. I want to do the following steps:

1. I m fetching some blogs from the server.
2. Adding blogs data to blogs state
3. Filtering a blog that is the same as URL param
4. Adding that blog to blog state

problem is coming at stape 4 when I am trying to add that particular blog to the blog state. When I am logging both states, the blog state is coming as empty array [].

```
function BlogDetail(props) {
  const [blog, setBlog] = useState([]);
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);

  let param = useParams();

  // Fetch blogs from server
  const getBlogs = () => {
    axios
      .get("/blog/all_blog/")
      .then((res) => {
        setBlogs(res.data);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  const getBlog = () => {
    const FixURL = (url) =>
      url
        .replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "")
        .replace(/\s+/g, "-")
        .toLowerCase();
    setBlog(blogs.filter((artical) => FixURL(artical.title) === param.id));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getBlogs();
    getBlog();
  }, []);

  console.log(blog);
  console.log(blogs);

  return <>...</>;
}
```

I also tried to warp this setBlog into callback function but does work for me, not gatting why the blog state is gating updated.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: You are not follow the pattern of React. React is single thread. You should change the position of your useEffect. Cut from below and paste on under the useParams. I hope it work

Answer (score 0):

1. `getBlog()` runs before `getBlogs()`'s fetch finishes, so there are no `blogs` to filter over. The contents of `getBlog()` could be moved to the `.then()` in `getBlogs()`, but that's not a good idea:
2. `blog` doesn't need to be state anyway, since it can be derived from `blogs` and params; you should just use [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) then.
3. There is no need for `FixURL` to be an inner function. It's cleaner to move it outside the component.
4. I assume you want a single blog (article) since the state atom is named `blog`, so I changed `.filter` to `find`.

```
const FixURL = (url) =>
  url
    .replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "")
    .replace(/\s+/g, "-")
    .toLowerCase();

function BlogDetail(props) {
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState();
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("/blog/all_blog/").then(({ data }) => setBlogs(data));
  }, []);

  const blog = React.useMemo(() => (blogs || []).find((article) => FixURL(article.title) === id));

  console.log(blog);
  console.log(blogs);

  return <>...</>;
}
```